# Немогу Вывести Элемент Массива (RedBeanPHP)

Tags: php, массивы, веб-программирование, redbeanphp

Есть Код:

```
$find = R::findAll('task','NAME LIKE ?', ['%'.$q.'%']);
    if($find){ // Если Массив не Пустой
        foreach($find as $res){
            echo $res['NAME'];
        }
    }
```

> var_dump($res);
>   object(RedBeanPHP\OODBBean)#15 (10) { ["properties":protected]=> array(11) { ["ID"]=> string(1) "1" ["NAME"]=> string(127) "Написать 4 положительных комментария в Instagram'e и пролайкать эти 4 поста" ["DESCR"]=> string(224) "Приветствую я начинающий Блогер, веду свой блог в Instagram'e По скольку сейчас развелось очень много недо блогеров, пропиар... " ["AUTHOR"]=> string(24) "Пользователь" ["CATEGORY"]=> string(10) "Клики" ["PRICE"]=> string(4) "7500" ["WATCHS"]=> string(2) "16" ["RATING"]=> string(1) "2" ["COMPLETS"]=> string(2) "11" ["NOT_COMPLETS"]=> string(1) "2" ["CREATE_DATE"]=> string(19) "2018-06-14 09:20:06" } ["__info":protected]=> array(5) { ["type"]=> string(4) "task" ["sys.id"]=> string(2) "id" ["sys.orig"]=> array(11)

**Проблема вот в чем:** 
Я пытаюсь произвести поиск по средством Библиотеки RedBeanPHP методом findAll() все хорошо, поиск сработал но проблема в том что когда я пытаюсь вывыести Элемент массива по Его Ключу(в моем случае это NAME), Ничего не Выводится...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю у вас PHP<7 версии. В таком случае, если вы хотите обращаться к объекту OODBBean как к массиву, вам необходимо его конвертировать в массив.

```
$find = $find->export();
```

И дальше обращаться к нему как к массиву.

p.s.

обратное преобразование для одной строки

```
$res = R::convertToBean('task', $find);
```

или для всего массива

```
$res = R::convertToBeans('task', $find);
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас `$find` имеет свойство объекта `(object)`, а нужно `(array)`.

Если вы хотите исправить, то выводите:

```
$res->NAME
```

Но, если хотите в формате:

```
$res['NAME']
```

То сделайте так:

```
$find = R::findAll('task','NAME LIKE ?', ['%'.$q.'%']);
$find = (array) $find;

if ($find) {
    foreach ($find as $res) {
        echo $res['properties']['NAME'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Преобразовал, так же ничего не выводится...

Comment: Покажите, что у вас при `print_r((array) $find);` выходит?

Comment: Array ( [*properties] => Array ( [ID] => 1 [NAME] => Написать 4 положительных комментария в Instagram'e и пролайкать эти 4 поста [DESCR] => Приветствую я начинающий Блогер, веду свой блог в Instagram'e По скольку сейчас развелось очень много недо блогеров, пропиар... [AUTHOR] => Пользователь [CATEGORY] => Клики [PRICE] => 7500 [WATCHS] => 16 [RATING] => 2 [COMPLETS] => 11 [NOT_COMPLETS] => 2 [CREATE_DATE] => 2018-06-14 09:20:06 ) [*__info] => Array ( [type] => task [sys.id] => id [sys.orig]

Comment: @JesusGVN, исправил код, попробуйте так, как у меня.

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @JesusGVN, еще раз исправил, попробуйте

Comment: Теперь просто ничего не выходит!

Comment: @JesusGVN, не понимаю зачем вам циклы, попробуйте `echo $find['properties']['NAME'];` без циклов

Comment: Да хоть без цикла, та же проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Вы работаете не с массивом, а с бином, поэтому

```
echo $res->name;
```

Метод find получает бин, а не массив.